# Can't run webcam in Eclipse

Tags: java

```
import JMyron.*;
public class WebCamera {
    public WebCamera() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    int height = 320, width = 240;
    JMyron my = new JMyron();

    void setup() {
        my.start(width, height);
        my.update();
        my.stop();
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {

        setup();
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

This is my simple program
What i have done is downloaded the JMyron library, imported the three .dll files into my java project folder (WebCam in my case), added the JMyron.jar file through the Add External Jars in Project menu and then wrote a simple code.
However, the project folder shows a red exclamation mark and the code terminates when i run it after compiling (for that i use ctrl + S)

The Problems shown are :

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    WebCam      Unknown Java Problem
>
> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Project 'WebCam' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\Sony\Desktop\Habe\Habe\opencv\javac.zip'    WebCam      Build path  Build Path Problem

Comment: javac is the compiler, neither an end user library, nor part of opencv. you must have done something wrong to eclipse

Comment: can it be that i have chosen a wrong compiler?

Comment: i was given the option of default sdk, sdk 1.6 or jre 6 envoirnment

Comment: I created another application and chose everything default and even chose different folders for source and application files, but now the error is : could not find the main class JMyron.JMyron

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the libraries correctly ?

Can you confirm that JMyron is not depending on a CV lib like http://code.google.com/p/javacv/ ?

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how to check that

Comment: I created another application and chose everything default and even chose different folders for source and application files, but now the error is : could not find the main class JMyron.JMyr