# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform JMyron.dll

Tags: java

i have imported the entire code for the example given at the http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/download.shtml for the java example, but the error given above is coming.
Can please anyone give clear guidelines on how to start a webcam through java on eclipse juno?
Whether to choose the .dlls given in the Processing Library or the ones in Java section on thr abovementioned site?
I recently posted a program earlier but that program refused to work
Here is the link to the previous question
[Can't run webcam in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15577002/cant-run-webcam-in-eclipse)
My machine is 64 bit, Windsows 7

Comment: If your jvm is 64 bits you cannot use a 32 bit dll.
The other way arround 64 bit dll on 32 bit machine does not workeither. Check those first and then verify if you can really access the path to your dll from java. Do you get some kind of "Unsatisfiedlink exception"?

Comment: can you tell me where to get the 32 bit jvm that works on 64 bit envoirnment?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-windows-i586.exe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113080/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform)